# Cannot resolve file location with MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to restore my old database using MSSQL Server Management Studio and everytime i get this error. I clearly dont understand what type of error is this?

[image: Could not access the location of the .bak file]

I am logged in using Windows Authentication. Any help would be great. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://deepindera.blogspot.ro/2010/10/database-engine-service-could-not.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a SQL script to do the restore, or are you using the SMS Restore dialog?  If you are not using the dialog, do so and see if you can pick the file.  If not, then it is a permission problem with your SQL admin account.